# cloudant gives status 500 creating database on bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloudant

The IBM Bluemix Cloudant service is randomly giving me a 500 status when creating a database.  Here is what is returned:

> status_code is 500
>   Unable to create database https://852ce941-f998-429e-a295-7161291dd938-bluemix.cloudant.com/order: Reason: {"error":"ok","reason":"ok"}

I am using `python-cloudant` to access Cloudant on Bluemix.  Which is returning a CloudantException with the above status code and reason.
It is strange that error and reason are both ok.  Is the database created okay or not?  If it is created okay, why the exception and 500 status?  I do a delete on the database which is successful right before I try to create it.  This only happens randomly.  Most of the time, the create database is successful.

Comment: Do you know what Bluemix cluster you're on? And approximately when you received the 500s? I know Cloudant recently underwent maintenance on the Bluemix `eu-gb` and `us-south` regions (https://status.ng.bluemix.net/).

Comment: Also, what version of the python library are you using? Thanks.

Comment: I am on dedicated bluemix at console.w3ibm.bluemix.net.  The 500s would have been around the time I posted here yesterday.  I put try sleep loops around all of my cloudant calls because the cloudant service is so flakey.  I haven't noticed the 500 errors today.  It may have gone away or the loops may eventually work hiding the failures.

Comment: I am using python cloudant version 2.0.0 and python 2.7.

Comment: I just upgraded cloudant to 2.3.0 to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm checking with some of the authors of the library and will let you know if I turn up anything.

Comment: As for the 500 on your dedicated Bluemix environment, I agree with joe's answer. That's something the Cloudant support team will investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this error before with the REST API. I think it is a problem with the Cloudant service and/or your service instance. Open up a support ticket with your service instance, and they should be able to look at the logs to solve the issue.